# Retrieve the System Date

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to retrieve the current system date, not the actual date, using C# then subtract 3 months to get the previous 3 months using a loop. I thought you can just do:

```
DateTime currMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3);
```

I was under the impression that DateTime.Now actually gave you the current system date, but according to the people who tested my code said it isn't getting the date.

Any insight or resources would be great!

Comment: If it's not getting the correct date, what is it getting? Can you provide an example of expected and actual results?

Comment: "According to people"? Test it yourself! It's easy enough. Don't believe a single word they say! Go on, test it!

Comment: It does get the system date.. I think it would be a good idea to gather more information for your users.. other than "It's not getting the date". This is what is (now) known as a "Shrug Report". Reference: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Comment: I'm going to be that guy for a moment in case there is a knowledge gap with web development.  If this is a web application, DateTime.Now represents the system date and time.  It will not adjust to the client visiting the page (for that you would need client script or the ability to determine what timezone the user is in and adjust the date accordingly).

Comment: How do you define "the actual date" vs "current system date"? Wait - is this a web application? Do you mean the user/browser's date vs the server's date?

Comment: I should clarify on this a bit. SO, according to my tests it is getting today's month (November) but the system is clocked back to some month that changes depending on what they change the system clock to (which sounds like really bad practice in my opinion) and it is not getting that date. So, I am not looking for the clients/user/browser date, I am looking for what the System's Date is. Does this make more sense?

Comment: @DavidF. You need to clarify the definitions. System Date/Server date/Program displayed date/TimeZone/Locales and what is present and what should be present. Please also clarify where the code is executing - what is 'System'? Where are you testing the same or another machine etc. etc... Get some screen shots or similar and put these all in the question. At the moment it's a finger in the air exercise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` gives you the *local* system date/time, so:

- It depends on the system clock
- It depends on the system time zone

It *sounds* like that's what you're after. It's not clear what you mean by "it isn't getting the date" but it looks correct to me, assuming that both of the above are what you want. To make it clearer that you want just the date, I'd suggest using [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) though, which is equivalent to `DateTime.Now.Date`.